# PHP echo date_format of an object directly

Tags: php

This doesnt produce an error for me but simply has no output. Can this not be done?
`echo date_format($result->deposit_due_date, "m-d-y")`

Comment: have you tried `echo date_format(date_create($result->deposit_due_date), "m-d-y");` ?

Comment: What does `$result->deposit_due_date` hold?

Comment: @gregSchmidt just holds the date in european format dd-mm-yyyy I am changing it to American format

Comment: @jpneey I just tried it and it worked. What is the significance of extra code there ?

Comment: So it's a string? `date_format` takes a `DateTimeInterface` object as a parameter. `date(strtotime($result->deposit_due_date), 'm-d-y')` might be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_format` takes a `DateTimeInterface object` as a parameter for it to return the formatted date.

Strings can be formatted to a `DateTimeInterface object` by using some built-in php functions such as `strtotime()` as commented by `@greg` at the comments, `date_create()` etc..

Once a string is formatted into a `DateTimeInterface object` you can now feed it directly as a parameter for `date_format()`.

```
<?php

$some_date = '2021-05-05'; // <- a date which is in string format 

echo date_format($some_date, 'y-m-d'); // <-- this will not produce any output for $some_date is not a DateTimeInterface object

// however the following will output the following  with it's format altered by date_format()

echo date_format(strtotime($some_date), 'y-m-d');
echo date_format(date_create($some_date), 'y-m-d');
```

Take note that you must still check if the string inputted to `strtotime()` and `date_create()` are valid to avoid unexpected outputs.